# Adding Displace modifier to an object but only on specific area

Tags: texturing

I'm an absolute beginner in blender. I tried to add a voronoi texture to the surface of my object. But I'd like to add it only to the red marked area. I tried it with UV Map, by selecting the faces, adding a new UV Map and so on...

Is there a simple way?

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to select the faces and assign them another material

Answer (score 1):

1. got into `Edit`Mode (with TAB key)
2. select the points and faces you wish to texture with a certain material
3. In the Properties-Panel, go to the `Material` section
4. If not already there, create the new Material and name it accordingly
5. With the correct points and faces still selected, assign the material with the `Assign` button

P.S. Make sure to assign a different material to the rest of the Mesh. In the example image, there is no other material, which will lead to the effect for the other faces to automatically use the only available material of the mesh for all these faces too until you assign them a dedicated material.

[image: Assign Material to parts of Object]

Done. You can leave Edit mode and go back to Object mode.

Comment: The problem with your example is, to beginners this may look as if only the selected faces will get the "Eyes" material. However, since it is the only single material on the object, it will automatically be assigned to the complete mesh (even without clicking the button) and you cannot "unassign" it from the other faces to make them have no material at all.

Comment: You're right, i added a clarification to the answer

Answer (score 0):

TLDR - (In at least recent versions,) there's a "Vertex Group" option within the Displace modifier that limits the application to only faces bordering those verts.

---

Have UV's mapped. I ran into unexpected results caused by bad UVs after a previously applied Mirror modifier.

Go to Layout or Modeling tab.

Be in Object mode.

`Alt-a` to deselect all if needed, then select the object that you want to partially displace. As per OP I'm assuming there is already a displace modifier. You can add it at the end instead.

`Tab` to enter Edit mode.

`Alt-a` to deselect all if needed; `Alt-h` to reveal hidden if necessary.

Set the selection mode to vertices. Choose some or all of the vertices that should be displaced. Xray and Hide are sometimes helpful for the selection.

Add the vertices to a Vertex Group with e.g. `Ctrl-G > Assign To New Group`.

In the right panel, click the wrench for Modifiers tab of your object and scroll to your Displace modifier.

Set Vertex Group to the one with the verts to displace (default name "Group"). The displacement is only applied to faces bordering these verts and it tapers off to meet any bordering verts that are not part of the vertex group.

In my image, I have set all verts other than the bottom surface and top surface to be part of my sole vertex group. I'm using it to keep my top and bottom surfaces flat while applying a displacement texture to my walls.
[image]

Comment: I am trying to drill voronai holes; if that's where you're working towards please post your results!